# Volver a la pagina de atras (c#, Xamarin, Android)

Tags: android, xamarin

tengo el siguiente código y necesitaría tanto si se ha guardado la configuración como si no, que se volviera a la página anterior.

```
private void Boton_press(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// 
// Guardar datos en archivo
String filename = "ruta";
String contenido = parametros;

try
{
// Aqui grabo el archivo
var res=DisplayAlert("Configuracion", "Configuracion guardada", "Ok","Cancel");
// cerrar y volver al principio, despues de guardar la configuracion
}
catch (Exception)
{
// no se pudo guardar la configuracion
DisplayAlert("Error", "Error al escribir fichero a memoria interna", "Ok");
// terminar la aplicacion
//NavigationPage MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
}
```

Con el NavigationPage, no me funcionó.

Gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre sobreescribir el método `OnBackPressed` y llamarlo desde un finally, que abra una nueva instancia de la otra actividad.

Comment: Amigo mira si esto te sirve de algo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42546151/8933039